# Tensorflow: how to manually shard a dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, distributed-tensorflow

I'm using the `MirroredStrategy` to perform multi-gpu training and it doesn't appear to be properly sharding the data. How do you go about manually sharding data?

I know that I could use the `shard` method for a `tf.data` dataset, but for that I need access to the worker ID and I can't figure out how to get that. How do I access the worker ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MirroredStrategy` runs on a single worker (for multiple workers there is [MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/experimental/MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy)). Because it runs on only one worker, `MirroredStrategy` runs a single `Dataset` pipeline without any data sharding. At each step, `MirroredStrategy` requests one dataset element per worker.

Comment: Is there a way to manually shard using MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy?

Comment: Yes, you can create your dataset using `strategy.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function(dataset_fn)`. tf.distribute will pass an `input_context` argument to your `dataset_fn`, which will tell you the current worker id via `input_context.input_pipeline_id`. See these docs for an example: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/experimental/MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy#experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function

Comment: How do you control the number of workers when training on a single machine? Will it automatically create one worker per GPU or is it instead one worker per machine?